# How do you draw a line from a border?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I currently have this HTML:

```css
#circle {
  background-color: orange;
  max-width: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  float:left;
}
#innerContent {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#pointerDiv{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"><span id='innerContent'>123</span></div><div id='pointerDiv'>text goes here</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve this effect:

[image: Desired effect]

Basically, a line that goes from the border to point to an element I can fill with text that explains the number. How do I do this?

Comment: Where is the element that contains the text?

Comment: Woops, my bad. Fixed!

Comment: Can the line always be the same length (or) can the on-screen position of your element containing the text vary?

Comment: The line can always be the same length, as the text always remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is one sample method to achieve this by using a pseudo-element and then positioning it absolutely as required.

The reason for the `left: -58px` is because the `margin-right` (I had modified it from the 20px in question to 50px in answer just for illustration) is 50px + the border of the box is a few px inside the circle and so that also had to be considered. The `width` of the line is made smaller than the `left` value so as to make the line end just before the `pointerDiv`.

Note that I have also added a `clear: both` to the `#circle` just in-case you want to add more such entries one below the other. If not required, it can be removed.

```css
#circle {
  background-color: orange;
  max-width: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
#innerContent {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#pointerDiv {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#pointerDiv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: -58px;
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"><span id='innerContent'>123</span>
</div>
<div id='pointerDiv'>text goes here</div>

<div id="circle"><span id='innerContent'>123</span>
</div>
<div id='pointerDiv'>some lengthy text goes here</div>

<div id="circle"><span id='innerContent'>123</span>
</div>
<div id='pointerDiv'>short txt</div>
```

Comment: Took a bit of adjusing the pointerDiv:before settings for my situation, but it works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a CSS border or a SVG to draw a line (may not be compatible with some browser)

```css
#circle {
  background-color: orange;
  max-width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
#innerContent {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#pointerDiv {
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#line-svg {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"><span id='innerContent'>123</span>
</div>
<svg id="line-svg">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:4" />
</svg>
<div id='pointerDiv'>text goes here</div>
```

Comment: An interesting answer, thanks! However, I'd rather use CSS only for compatibility reasons.

Comment: SVG is very CSS3 like so definitely better go with old school CSS

Comment: Nice alternate idea mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use pseudo elements? I've created a *basic* mockup below:

```css
.circle {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "hi";
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  right: -85%;
  top: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 55px;
    height: 60px;
  width:60px;
}
.wrapper{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="tooltip">text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost similar ideas mate, but OP can accept only one answer so I wanted to reward your efforts. Please don't consider as sympathetic but more as mutual appreciation of similar thoughts.

Comment: @Harry: Most of our answers are *fairly* similar (well, most of the time anyway). So it's usually fastest answer to post between, well, you me Web-tiki and chipChocolate.py :P