# Create line connecting two DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a relationship editor. The user create some elements and is able to link them creating a relationship (bidirectional). I've created the first part (users creating elements). Now I need to create lines connecting two DIVs when users double click an element, for example.

I know that may have a couple of ways to do it, but actually I have no idea how to start it. **What would be a starting point?**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#BtInsert").button()
    .click(function() {

      var pad = "000000"
      var cor = "" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      cor = "#" + pad.substring(0, pad.length - cor.length) + cor;

      var newDIV = document.createElement('div');

      $(newDIV).addClass("base")
        .appendTo($("#container"))
        .html('N')
        .dblclick(function() {
          alert('Want to start to create a line from this div to another double click');
        })
        .draggable({
          containment: "parent"
        })
        .css({
          left: Math.floor(Math.random() * ($("#container").width() - $(".base").width())),
          top: Math.floor(Math.random() * ($("#container").width() - $(".base").width()))
        })
        .css("background-color", cor);
    })
});
```

```css
#BtInsert {
  top: 405px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#container {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.base {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
  vertical-alignment: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #CCC;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: width 3s, height 3s, border-radius 3s, line-height 3s, box-shadow 3s;
  transition: width 3s, height 3s, border-radius 3s, line-height 3s, box-shadow 3s;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
.base:hover {
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #333;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888888;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, border-radius 1s, line-height 1s, box-shadow 1s;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, border-radius 1s, line-height 1s, box-shadow 1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
</div>
<a href="#" id="BtInsert">
    Insert an element
</a>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nizamabreu/8easj6fg/8/)

Comment: Your question is not an exact duplicate as you are asking for dynamic creation of line but you can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021014/how-do-you-draw-a-line-from-a-border/28021250#28021250) for an idea on how to create the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to use SVG instead of HTML for this kind of representations. you will have more flexibility in drawing shapes in SVG.

You can take a look at http://d3js.org/ or http://raphaeljs.com/

See this examples:

- <strike>http://bl.ocks.org/enoex/6201948</strike>
- <strike>http://blog.stephenboak.com/2012/06/15/d3-flow-vis-tutorial.html</strike>
  -> https://web.archive.org/web/20130108020533/http://blog.stephenboak.com:80/2012/06/15/d3-flow-vis-tutorial.html

it's doing something similar to what you want.

Comment: The second example is just like I want to do. Thanks.

Comment: Both links are broken now

Comment: second link archived via wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130108020533/http://blog.stephenboak.com:80/2012/06/15/d3-flow-vis-tutorial.html